# setStreamVolume on Android 7

Tags: android, delphi, android-audiomanager, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have this code to set all incoming calls to max volume:

```
var
  RingingManager: JAudioManager;
begin
  RingingManager:= TJAudioManager.Wrap((TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.AUDIO_SERVICE) as ILocalObject).GetObjectID); 

  if Assigned(FRingingManager) then
    begin
      try
        FRingingManager.setRingerMode(TJAudioManager.JavaClass.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
        Sleep(2000);
        RingingManager.setStreamVolume(TJAudioManager.JavaClass.STREAM_RING, FRingingManager.getStreamMaxVolume(TJAudioManager.JavaClass.STREAM_RING), 0);
      finally
        RingingManager:= nil;
      end;
    end;
end;
```

On device SAMSUNG SM-A510 (Android 7.0) ***this code works well***.
Ringing is increased from **0 to max**, from **vibration (only) to max** and from **silent mode to max**.

On device SAMSUNG SM-A520F (Android 7.0) ***this code does not work***.
The only thing that works properly is ringing incrasing from **1 to max**. Nothing else works.

Do not know where the bug is?